# Flutter apps are changed

Tags: flutter

I was encountering issues configuring a Firebase app in my Flutter project.
To troubleshoot, I made various changes based on online suggestions, including:
Modifying the minSdkVersion.
Upgrading/downgrading Flutter.
Other unspecified modifications.
Current Situation:

Previously successful assembleDebug task now shows "Flutter launching" output.
New Projects:
Android build.gradle files,Android manifest.xml file content and overall structure have significantly changed compared to before.

**app/src/build.gradle**
before

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Release build configuration
            
        }
        debug {
            // Debug build configuration
          
        }
    }
    
   
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**then**

```
    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localPro
```

**build.gradle file**

*before*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Android Gradle Plugin version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        // Google Services plugin version
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**then**

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**What caused these unexpected changes in both existing and newly created Flutter projects after attempting to resolve Firebase configuration issues?Is this abnormal? then how can I get back?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.